# Custom cell is Duplicating the properties of the other cell in the same Tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a custom cell for my UITableview in which I am having few UILabels. In one label I am setting it's color to red.That is working very fine for me. But As soon as I am reloading the TableView by Egorefresh Table delegate Methods the color of the label of other cells also start changing to red color. I don't know why this problem is coming and it is causing a lot of disgust to me.

This is the code for the TableView datasource method cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
  forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // Set the Frame for BackgroundView of Cell.
    NSDictionary * insuranceDic = [arr_insurance objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    insuranceDic = [[AppDelegate sharedInstance] removeNullsFromDictonary:insuranceDic];
    InsuranceCell * mycell = (InsuranceCell *)cell;
    if([[insuranceDic valueForKey:@"active"] isEqualToString:@"N"]){
        //TTTRegexAttributedLabel * label = [[TTTRegexAttributedLabel alloc] init];
        mycell.lbl_insuranceName.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)",
       [insuranceDic valueForKey:@"insurance_name"],@"Inactive"];
        mycell.lbl_insuranceName.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        //[label setText:cell.lbl_insuranceName.text withRegex:@"(Inactive)" withFont: 
    [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] withColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
    else{
        mycell.lbl_insuranceName.text = [insuranceDic valueForKey:@"insurance_name"];
    }
}
```

And on reloading the table view from these methods the problem is occuring :

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate Methods

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
// For Top Pull to refresh.
    [_refreshHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];
   //For Bottom Pull to refresh.
    [pullToBottomRefreshManager_ tableViewScrolled];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate: 
  (BOOL)decelerate{
    // For Top Pull to refresh.
    [_refreshHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDidEndDragging:scrollView];
    //For Bottom Pull to refresh.
    [pullToBottomRefreshManager_ tableViewReleased];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark EGORefreshTableHeaderDelegate Methods

// Belowline is for stop refresh indicator
//[_refreshHeaderView 
  egoRefreshScrollViewDataSourceDidFinishedLoading:self.tableView];

- (void)egoRefreshTableHeaderDidTriggerRefresh:(EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view{
    // When we going to refresh the data we need to reset the start varible to 1
    // and also removeallthe previous objects from the array.
    str_start = @"1";
    [self getInsuranceList];
}

- (BOOL)egoRefreshTableHeaderDataSourceIsLoading:(EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view{
      return isReloading; // should return if data source model is reloading
}

- (NSDate*)egoRefreshTableHeaderDataSourceLastUpdated: 
  (EGORefreshTableHeaderView*)view{

      return [NSDate date]; // should return date data source was last changed

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark MNMBottomPullToRefreshManagerClient Methods
- (void)bottomPullToRefreshTriggered:(MNMBottomPullToRefreshManager *)manager {

   // Here we are incrementing start with records per page means start+=recordsperpare 
   or start+=20.
   str_start = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[str_start intValue]+
   [str_recordsPerPage intValue]];
   [self getInsuranceList];
}
```

This is the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  
    (NSIndexPath
    *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    InsuranceCell  * cell = [InsuranceCell dequeOrCreateInTable:tableView];
     //    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[[InsuranceCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
    NSDictionary * insuranceDic = [arr_insurance objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    insuranceDic = [[AppDelegate sharedInstance] removeNullsFromDictonary:insuranceDic];
    cell.lbl_insuranceNo.text = [insuranceDic valueForKey:@"insurance_no"];
    cell.lbl_groupNo.text = [insuranceDic valueForKey:@"group_no"];
    cell.lbl_priority.text = [self getPriorityDescFromCode:[insuranceDic    
    valueForKey:@"priority"]];
    cell.lbl_startDate.text = [insuranceDic valueForKey:@"start_date"];
    cell.lbl_endDate.text = [insuranceDic valueForKey:@"end_date"];
    cell.lbl_copay.text = [insuranceDic valueForKey:@"copay"];

   // This Condition is For setting alternate (White/SkyBlue) Background color for cell.
   //    if (fmod(indexPath.row, 2)==0) {
   //        cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorFromRGBIntegers:237       green:243 blue:249 alpha:1];
   //        
   //    }
   //    else{
   //        cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorFromRGBIntegers:250   green:250 blue:250 alpha:1];
   //    }

   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
   return cell;
 }
```

Comment: where is ur cellForRowAtIndexPath method ??

Comment: The code was first done in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method but the same error was coming there. So I coded in willDisplayCell and By mistake named it above as cellForRowAtIndexPath. So Please suggest something for the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you could add your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation.

Given the information you provide I suppose you are reusing cells and not resetting the color before.
You need to override `- (void)prepareForReuse` in your `InsuranceCell`
and reset any cell specific properties.

Sample Implementation:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    // reset the label text color to your default color (e.g. black)
    self.lbl_insuranceName.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

You need to implement this method within your **InsuranceCell**.

You need to understand, that with the default implementation of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` your TableViewCells will be reused. This means you need to reset every property explicitly, before you reuse a cell. The most convenient way to do this, is overriding the `prepareForReuse` method, as shown above.

Comment: This is My cellForRowAtIndexPath method code: You can take a look at it and I am getting your point about reusing the cell but not understanding about how to remove this anomaly.

Comment: override the 'pepareForReuse' method in your InsuranceCell.

Comment: G. can you please explain that what to write in that method and where to implement that method?

Comment: Added the info in my answer.